# What does a typedef with operator "> >" mean?

Tags: c++, templates

What does this statement in C++ mean. I came across by reading about Typelists.

I don't understand what the operator ">" stands for in typelist? I have never used this so far in C++ template stuff?

```
template 
struct typelist
{
    typedef H head;
    typedef T tail;
};


typedef typelist > >
    floating_point_types;
```

Thanks for some short explanations!
¿Is this variadic templates?

Comment: This looks pretty much like a formatting error to me! The template definition is also missing what the template is about.

Comment: Where were you reading about typelists?  The code fragment makes approximately zero sense as shown, so you should go back and have another look at the original material.

Comment: lolz, Jonathan... "approximately" =P

Comment: ok then it is a html typo huch! i dont know the site: google the above struct.... thx for answering this stupid question! lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code fragment looks wrong. From the names and the context I *guess* that it was meant to look like this:

```
template <typename H, typename T>
struct typelist
{
    typedef H head;
    typedef T tail;
};


typedef typelist<float, typelist<double, long double> >
    floating_point_types;
```

The original code likes as if it was pasted into a HTML document and, thus, had sequences of '<...>' removed.

Of course, with C++ 2011 we wouldn't need to do something like this. We could instead just use variadic templates:

```
template <typename... T> struct typelist {};

typedef typelist<float, double, long double> floating_point_types;
```

Comment: Very nicely done given the information you have, however, shouldn't it be `typedef typelist<float, typelist<double, long double> > > floating_point_types;` instead?

Comment: @Zshazz: Yes, indeed - I got a bit carried away, I guess. I'll fix it.